# How to show the value when mouseOver from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, graph, charts, mouseover

I'm using the library from charts.js, where I've got this graph which looks like a doughnut. My question is, how can I get the specific value to show when I'm hovering over the object?

The code below:

```
var doughnutData = [
        {
            value : 30,
            color :"#F7464A"
        },
        {
            value : 50,
            color : "#46BFBD"
        },
        {
            value : 100,
            color : "#DD3234"
        },
        {
            value : 40,
            color : "#949FB1"
        },
        {
            value : 120,
            color : "#4D5360"
        }
    ];

    doughnutData.toString();

var myDoughnut = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(doughnutData);
```

[image]

This is the "graph", so, how can I with this array, tell that I'm holding the pointer/mouse over a certain piece of the doughnut and show its value?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using JQuery for this? If JQuery is a possibility, I would like to propose a solution. :)

Comment: @AnchovyLegend, I have to go with this, that's the issue... :/ We're comparing D3.js, Charts.js and so on.

Comment: JQuery is nothing more than a bunch of javascript helper functions after all, it will make your life so much easier :)